# Python program to combine two dictionary adding values for common keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I need to combine them. I need to sum the values of similar keys and the different keys leave them without sum.

These are the two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300}
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}
```

The expected results:

```
d3= {'b': 400, 'd': 400, 'a': 400, 'c': 300}
```

I have successfully made the sum and added them to this third dictionary, but I couldn't know, how to add the different values.

My try

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300}
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}
d3 = {}

for i, j in d1.items():
    for x, y in d2.items():
        if i == x:
            d3[i]=(j+y)


print(d3)


My results = {'a': 400, 'b': 400}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Andrej's answer (I LOVE list/dict comprehensions), but here's yet another thing:

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300}
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}

d3 = dict(d1) # don't do `d3=d1`, you need to make a copy
d3.update(d2) 

for i, j in d1.items():
    for x, y in d2.items():
        if i == x:
            d3[i]=(j+y)


print(d3)
```

I realised your own code can be "fixed" by first copying values from d1 and d2.

`d3.update(d2)` adds d2's contents to d3, but it overwrites values for common keys. (Making d3's contents `{'a':300, 'b':200, 'c':300, 'd':400}`)

However, by using your loop after that, we correct those common values by assigning them the sum. :)

Answer (score 3):

Version without `collections.Counter`:

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300}
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}

d = {k: d1.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0) for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys()}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'b': 400, 'c': 300, 'd': 400, 'a': 400}
```

EDIT: With `for`-loop:

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c':300}
d2 = {'a': 300, 'b': 200, 'd':400}

d = {}
for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys():
    d[k] = d1.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0)

print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , Sir. How does it work this one sir?

Comment: @Chen `dict.keys()` returns instance of `dict_keys` class, which is `set()`-like object. I combine the `dict_keys()` from `d1` and `d2` to obtain set of all keys in both dictionaries. Then I use dict comprehension to create new dict with sum of values from each dictionary (with default value of `0` if key doesn't exists in respective dictionary.

Comment: List/set/dict/generator comprehension make a list/set/dict/generator (depending on brackets used) out of a math-like notation. (E.g. numbers divisible by 2 from A would be in maths considered `{k : k in A and k=0 modulo 2}`, in Python `{k for k in A if k%2==0}`). - It's basically a compressed `for` loop. And it's very powerful when you learn how to use it. :)

Comment: @Chen I edited my answer with `for`-loop version. It's identical to the `dict`-comprehension version

Comment: @AndrejKesely why did you put 0 with get(k,0)?

Comment: @Chen For example in dict `d1` the key `d` is missing, so function `d1.get('d', 0)` will return `0` as default value instead of raising error.

Comment: @AndrejKesely 

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does what you need:

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 300}
d2 = {"a": 300, "b": 200, "d": 400}

d3 = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)
# Counter({'a': 400, 'b': 400, 'd': 400, 'c': 300})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. I know this way, sir. I'm trying to solve it with for loops.

Comment: @Chen you are welcome! (and there is no  need to be **this** polite here! no one will be offended if you do not address them with 'sir'...)

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new for this site. :)

Comment: @Chen there is nothing to forgive! it is refreshing see there are also people with good manners here! ;)